# Pass part of filename as parameter in function

Tags: python

I'm writing a function to import .dta files that will have the name structure but with different prefixes. How do I reference this prefix in a string filepath name? For example, something like

```
 def import_stata(code):
    df=pd.read_stata("code_dataset.dta")
    return df
```

Where code is the prefix that will change. Right now I'm getting an error saying that code_dataset doesn't exist.

Thanks!

Comment: `df=pd.read_stata(code+"code_dataset.dta")`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following string concatenation:

```
def import_stata(code):
  df=pd.read_stata(code+"_dataset.dta")
  return df
```